# The maths of free fall and near free fall

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, acceleration, free-fall

I saw Usain Bolt's video today and the source said that they were in a near free fall ([Usain bolt races in reduced gravity](https://rumble.com/v6e2yp-usain-bolt-races-in-reduced-gravity.html))

The question that came up to my mind is how the math works regarding free fall and near free fall and how to calculate the resulting apparent reduced/lackof gravity

Let's say I want to have 0.5 gravity, how do I calculate my free fall speed or acceleration?

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. He's still on planet Earth, the gravity acting on him is still $g$. Can you post the link to whatever it is you are citing?

Comment: Hi, I linked to the video directly. I mean the apparent gravity. I know that g is always there. Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an accelerated frame of reference, acceleration of the frame is perceived as additional apparent force (systemic force). So everything measured against the accelerating airplane, is just computed with this additional force, which is also proportional to the mass of the object (just like gravity). This means that accelerations just subtract. For freefall (and vertical acceleration of the airplane), we have:

$$ma_r=mg-ma_p=m(g-a_p)$$
where $a_p$ is the acceleration of the plane (frame of reference) and $a_r$ is apparent acceleration (fake g) perceived for the object. I'm counting all accelerations to be positive in downward direction to avoid additional negative signs.

After this, all the kinematic equations are exactly the same as always. Just use any calculation done for regular gravity and replace $g$ with $g-a_p$.

Comment: Thank you for the formula and for the explanation about the accelerated frame of reference